# cython: relative cimport beyond main package is not allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, cython, cimport

I am trying to use explicit relative imports in cython. From the [release notes](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/CHANGES.rst) it seems like relative imports should work after cython 0.23, and I'm using 0.23.4 with python 3.5. But I get this strange error that I cannot find many references to. The error is only from the cimport:

```
driver.pyx:4:0: relative cimport beyond main package is not allowed
```

The directory structure is:

```
    myProject/
        setup.py
        __init__.py
        test/
            driver.pyx
            other.pyx
            other.pxd
```

It seems like I'm probably messing up in setup.py so I included all the files below.

`setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension('other', ['test/other.pyx'],),
    Extension('driver', ['test/driver.pyx'],),
]

setup(
    name='Test',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    include_dirs=["test/"],
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

`driver.pyx`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from . import other
from . cimport other
```

`other.pyx`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

HI = "Hello"

cdef class Other:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Test"

    cdef get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

`other.pxd`

```
cdef class Other:
    cdef get_name(self)
```

I've tried moving `__init__.py` into `test/`. I've tried running `setup.py` in the `test` directory (adjusting the `include_dirs` appropriately). They both give the same error.

If I do `cimport other` and remove the `.` it works but this is a toy example and I need relative imports so other folders can import properly. This is the only [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/wWxLMuHc56Q) I can find for this error and I'm pretty confident my issue is different.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56115159/1959808

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only other [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/wWxLMuHc56Q) I could find of this error was in [hal.pyx](https://github.com/machinekit/machinekit/blob/9e5dedd360fddd31cb8963a714f7297519c6bd4e/src/hal/cython/machinekit/hal.pyx) of the [machinekit project](https://github.com/machinekit/machinekit/blob/9e5dedd360fddd31cb8963a714f7297519c6bd4e/src/hal/cython/setup.py). I was pretty confident that this was a different error but today I realized that after that error was solved machinekit was working which means explicit relative imports must work. Their `setup.py` file refers to `linuxcnc` which isn't in the directory tree but I guess is created at some point during compile time. The important thing is that the `include_dirs` includes the parent directory instead of the child directory.

Translated to my project structure it would mean I put `myProject` in `include_dirs` instead of `test/`. After read this [guide](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html) for the second time I finally started to understand a little of how python thinks of packages. The problem was that the `include_dirs` was the child directory. It seems like this effectively made cython view it as a single flat directory in which case no relative imports would be allowed? An error like this might have made it more clear:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I still don't have a sufficiently deep understanding to know exactly what was going on but luckily the solution was relatively simple. I just changed the `include_dirs` to make cython recognize the nested file structure:

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension('other', ['test/other.pyx'],),
    Extension('driver', ['test/driver.pyx'],),
]

setup(
    name='Test',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    include_dirs=["."],
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

It all works now!

Comment: What about including a [`__init__.pxd`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html#init-pxd) in the directory `test/`?

Comment: Ah that's a good idea :) did that work for you?

Comment: Adding an `__init__.pxd` requires to be combined with at least one other change to work, please see my (newly added) answer. Also, this other change works also with `__init__.py` in place of `__init__.pxd`, so an `__init__.pxd` is not necessary (but an `__init__.p*` *is* necessary, either a `*.py` or a `.pxd`.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least four solutions to the Cythonization error (these results are with `cython == 0.29.24`):

1. adding the file `example_package/__init__.pxd` *and* changing the names of the `Extension`s being built to be submodules of the module being built, i.e., `example_package.other` and `example_package.driver` (in the question these would be `Test.other` and `Test.driver`).

   This change is anyway necessary for importing the installed submodules `driver` and `other`, as described below. Note that the installed package is actually a *namespace package* in this case, due to absence of the keyword parameter and argument `packages=['example_package']`, as discussed below.
2. adding the file `example_package/__init__.py` *and* changing the names of the `Extension`s being built to be submodules of the module being built, i.e., `example_package.other` and `example_package.driver`. Even in this case, where an `__init__.py` is present, the installed package `example_package` will be a namespace package. Turning it into a regular package requires passing `packages=['example_package']` to the function `setuptools.setup`.

   Likewise to adding an `__init__.pxd`, this change is necessary for importing the installed submodules.
3. adding the file `example_package/__init__.pxd` *and* changing the `cimport` statement to an absolute `cimport` inside the file `example_package/driver.pyx` (The package builds and installs with this alternative, but does not import, due to the need to also change the names of `Extension`s):

   ```
    from . import other
    from example_package cimport other
   ```
4. adding the file `example_package/__init__.py` *and* changing the `cimport` statement to an absolute `cimport` inside the file `example_package/driver.pyx`, as done in the previous item. The package builds and installs with this, but does not import.

The question is explicitly asking for [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports), so in that sense, the first two alternatives are the answers to the question, because they do work with relative imports.

Either of the four changes listed above avoids the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from . import other
from . cimport other
^
------------------------------------------------------------

example_package/driver.pyx:2:0: relative cimport beyond main package is not allowed
```

but as already noted above, and also discussed below, the change of `Extension` names of the first or second alternatives is necessary for importing the installed submodules (additionally passing the parameter and keyword argument `packages=[PACKAGE_NAME]` in the fourth alternative allows the Python package `example_package` to import, but not its submodules `driver` and `other`).

### Modified `setup.py`

The file `setup.py` that I recommend, with all additional changes (not only those changes necessary for building and installing, listed above) is:

```py
"""Installation script."""
import os
import setuptools


try:
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
    cy_ext = f'{os.extsep}pyx'
except ImportError:
    # this case is intended for use when installing from
    # a source distribution (produced with `sdist`),
    # which, as recommended by Cython documentation,
    # should include the generated `*.c` files,
    # in order to enable installation in absence of `cython`
    print('`import cython` failed')
    cy_ext = f'{os.extsep}c'


PACKAGE_NAME = 'example_package'


def run_setup():
    """Build and install package."""
    ext_modules = extensions()
    setuptools.setup(
        name=PACKAGE_NAME,
        ext_modules=ext_modules,
        packages=[PACKAGE_NAME],
        package_dir={PACKAGE_NAME: PACKAGE_NAME})


def extensions():
    """Return C extensions, cythonize as needed."""
    extensions = dict(
        other=setuptools.extension.Extension(
            f'{PACKAGE_NAME}.other',
            sources=[f'{PACKAGE_NAME}/other{cy_ext}'],),
        driver=setuptools.extension.Extension(
            f'{PACKAGE_NAME}.driver',
            sources=[f'{PACKAGE_NAME}/driver{cy_ext}'],))
    if cy_ext == f'{os.extsep}pyx':
        ext_modules = list()
        for k, v in extensions.items():
            c = cythonize(
                [v],
                # show_all_warnings=True  # this line requires `cython >= 3.0`
                )
            ext_modules.append(c[0])
    else:
        ext_modules = list(extensions.values())
    return ext_modules


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_setup()
```

### Other changes

The other changes in this answer are not necessary for successfully building and installing the package, but recommended for other reasons. For some of the other changes, I describe the motivation below.

Note that:

- only adding `example_package/__init__.pxd` or `example_package/__init__.py` is insufficient, and
- only changing the `Extension` names is insuffient, and
- only changing the `cimport` statement to `from example_package cimport other` is insufficient.

Two of these changes are needed together for building and installing, i.e., one of the four alternatives listed earlier.

For being able to *import* the extension modules built from the Cython sources `driver.pyx` and `other.pyx`, it is also necessary to change the  names of the extensions to:

- `Extension('example_package.other', ...)`
- `Extension('example_package.driver', ...)`

Note that this makes `import` work because now `example_package` has become a [*namespace package*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#namespace-packages) (CPython [glossary entry](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-namespace-package)):

```py
>>> 
<module 'example_package' (namespace)>
>>> import example_package.driver
>>> import example_package.other
```

(Also, I have omitted the parameter `include_dirs` of `setuptools.setup` in the `setup.py` file that I used, and which I include below.)

These changes are needed for building and installing the package, and for importing the extension modules. For *importing* the installed package from Python in case it did not include any extensions modules (and thus had not become a namespace package):

- a file `__init__.py` needs to be added in the directory `example_package/` (which in the question is the directory `Test/`), and
- the keyword argument `packages=[`example_package`],` needs to be passed to the function `setuptools.setup`.

Otherwise, the statement `import example_package` will raise a `ModuleNotFoundError`. The addition of an `__init__.py` file is also necessary to make the package a [*regular package*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages) (CPython [glossary entry](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-regular-package)), which is usually what is intended, instead of a namespace package.

### Whether to use an `__init__.pxd`

A regular Python package includes an `__init__.py` file. An `__init__.pxd` file is only relevant in case other packages need the `*.pxd` headers. If this is not the case, it seems that the file `example_package/__init__.py` suffices, since the four solutions above are essentially two solutions, each with either `__init__.py` or `__init__.pxd` as alternatives.

So my recommendation for files and their arrangement is:

```
.
├── example_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── driver.pyx
│   ├── other.pxd
│   └── other.pyx
└── setup.py
```

### Both changes are needed

Only adding the `__init__.pxd` file raises the cythonization error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from . import other
from . cimport other
^
------------------------------------------------------------

example_package/driver.pyx:3:0: relative cimport beyond main package is not allowed
```

and only changing the `cimport` statement (without an `__init__.pxd`) raises the cythonization error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
#!/usr/bin/env python
from . import other
from example_package cimport other
^
------------------------------------------------------------

example_package/driver.pyx:3:0: 'example_package.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
#!/usr/bin/env python
from . import other
from example_package cimport other
^
------------------------------------------------------------

example_package/driver.pyx:3:0: 'example_package/other.pxd' not found
```

### Naming the package

Above I write `example_package` as the package's name, though I did build and install the example also with the name `Test/` as it is named in the question, in order to ensure that this indeed works, and so that the minimal changes needed are the `__init__.pxd` file and the `from example_package cimport other`.

For uniformity, I actually also renamed the directory to `Test/` when running `setup.py` with this name of the package, but I am not on a case-sensitive filesystem at the moment, so I do not know whether a directory named `test/` together with the keyword argument `name='Test',` in `setup.py`, as in the question, would have caused issues on a case-sensitive filesystem.

So:

- using `Test` as package name and `Test` as directory name worked for me for building and installing, and
- using `test` as package name and `test` as directory name worked for me for building and installing.

I recommend using another package name. Also, for reasons described below:

- Importing when the package is named `Test` is done with the statement `import Test`. Writing `import test` will import *another* package (see below).
- using `test` as package name does not import the installed `test` package, for reasons explained below, even if an `__init__.py` file is added.

In any case, for reasons explained below, my recommendation is to change the package name, even if it is intended to be an auxiliary package that is intended to be used only as a test harness for the main package.

Also, lowercase package naming is mandated by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), thus leading to `test`, which may be understood to be a directory of tests, which is not the case if this actually is intended to be an example of a main package.

The error that happens *after* building and installing, when the package and directory are named `test` is (the dots ... are the result of editing the actual output):

```py
>>> import test
>>> test
<module 'test' from '.../lib/python3.9/test/__init__.py'>
```

In other words, CPython includes a package called [`test`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/test.html):

> The `test` package contains all regression tests for Python as well as the modules `test.support` and `test.regrtest`.

Therefore, the name `test` cannot be used for an example package that is intended to be imported after installation (though the package does get built and installed, and even uninstalled by `pip uninstall -y test`, fine).

Another detail is that `from test cimport other` is actually wrong, even though it compiles, because had the built `test` package actually been magically imported somehow (in the presence of CPython's `test` package), at runtime this `cimport` statement would have defaulted to CPython's `test` package. Nonetheless, Cython's translation may transform this `cimport` to some other form that would have actually imported from `test.other` of the built package. Since the import of the installed `test` package appears to be impossible in the presence of CPython's `test` package, it is unknown whether this `cimport` would have raised a runtime error.

Also, note that:

> **Note:** The `test` package is meant for internal use by Python only. It is documented for the benefit of the core developers of Python. Any use of this package outside of Python’s standard library is discouraged as code mentioned here can change or be removed without notice between releases of Python.

Between all experiments, I run `rm -rf build dist *.egg-info test/*.c`.
So before changing the file arrangement to the one shown earlier, what I used is the same with the question.

### Renaming the package to `example_package`

I changed the name of the package to `example_package`, assuming that `test/` contains the actual package to be installed, based on the argument given to the parameter `name=` within the file `setup.py` of the question.

The motivation for this renaming is that "test" or "tests" is usually used to name the directory of tests that accompany a Python package. There are many arrangements for such directories, and for how the tests are used. In the next section, I discuss my suggestion for arranging tests.

Regarding possibilities, arrangements other than what I describe in the next section have been used in general, including placing the tests in directories *within* the package itself. Given that the question writes `myProject/`, and has a file `myProject/__init__.py`, I am not sure whether the question actually uses such an arrangement.

In that case, though, `driver` and `other` would actually be test modules. Though installing the tests as a separate package (called `Test` in the question), which is what the module `myProject/setup.py` does, suggests that `driver` and `other` are the main package's modules, and thus that the main package is called "Test".

If not, i.e. if `driver` and `other` are actually test modules, and `setup.py` is *not* the main package's setup script, but instead a setup script that builds and installs an "auxiliary" package that is intended for only testing the main package (which may in this case be named "myProject", with a `setup.py` present in the directory that contains the directory `myProject/` of the question), then my renaming of `Test` to `example_package/` would not correspond to this being the main package. (It is also interesting to have a test-harness package that includes Cython code and thus requires to be compiled--and possibly installed.)

In that case, perhaps `Test` could be renamed instead to `tests_of_example_package`. In other words, in that case it is relevant to include the word "test" in the package's name, though it seems that qualifying the package as auxiliary to `example_package` is explicit. Explicit is better than implicit ([PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

(Tests sometimes are arranged as packages (using `__init__.py`), even when not installing this as an auxiliary Python package (intended as only a test harness of the main Python package it accompanies). The motivation is to enable importing common modules of the test suite that are used by multiple test modules, but are not themselves modules that are run directly by the test runner.)

If this is the main package, then I assume that "Test" was used for the purpose of writing an example in the example. If so, then my only reason for renaming (lowercase aside) is to distinguish the main package itself from its tests.

Lowercase names for Python packages are mandated by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names):

> Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.

The underscore in `example_package` is only for the sake of example.

### Arranging tests

Tests might be placed in a `test/` directory that is in the same directory with the directory that contains the Python package, and is named after the package. I strongly recommend this approach, for example (this tree was created with the program [`tree`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(command))):

```
.
├── example_package
│   └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── module_name_test.py
```

For testing without accidentally importing the package `example_package` from its source directory, but from where it is installed (usually under `site-packages/`), I recommend in all cases first `cd`ing to the directory `tests/` *before* running any tests. This is the most reliable approach to testing, does not rely on how each testing framework works, how the testing framework's various configuration options work, how the options interact with each other, nor how bugs in the testing framework itself affect testing.

In this way, the package source can be placed inside the directory `example_package`, without any reason to use any other directory arrangement.

### Shebangs in Python modules

The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) inside the `*.pyx` files can be removed, because it has no effect. The shebang line is treated by [Cython](http://cython.org) as a Python comment line that is moved to inside a C comment somewhere later inside the `*.c` files that Cython generates from the `*.pyx` files. So it has no effect. I am not aware of any use of shebang lines in C sources that are intended to be compiled by directly calling [`gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org) (or another C compiler), as Cython does (whether Cython calls `gcc`, or another compiler depends on the system, environment path, environment variables, and other information).

Also, the shebang is only relevant to Python modules that might be executed as executables. This is not intended to be the case for modules inside a Python package, so shebang lines are almost never used there.

An exception might be a package module that might be infrequently be run directly during development, e.g., for experimentation or debugging purposes. Nonetheless, such a module would be expected to have a [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) stanza.

So Python modules to which a shebang is relevant, also typically have a `__main__` stanza.

For completeness, `setup.py` is intended to be run as `__main__`, and does have a `__main__` stanza, but the way setup scripts are run (when not using `pip`--using `pip` is strongly recommended) is by `python setup.py`, so there is no need for a shebang in `setup.py` (no shebang appears there in the question--I just mention this for completeness).

### Importing `setuptools` in `setup.py`, instead of `distutils`

The `distutils` module]() is [deprecated as of Python 3.10](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0632/#specification), as specified in [PEP 632](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/distutils.html), and will be removed in Python 3.12.

### Switching when Cython is absent to the extension `.c`, instead of `.pyx`

This is in accord with [Cython recommendations](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules):

> It is strongly recommended that you distribute the generated `.c` files as well as your Cython sources, so that users can install your module without needing to have Cython available.

### Uppercase names for module-scope variables in `setup.py` that remain unchanged ("constants")

Module-scope Python variables that are intended to be used as constants, i.e., remain unchanged after the initial assignment, are mandated by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) to have identifiers that are uppercase with underscores:

> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include `MAX_OVERFLOW` and `TOTAL`.

Hence the identifier `PACKAGE_NAME`.

### Formatted strings

I used [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals), which require Python >= 3.6.

### Arranging code as functions within the module `setup.py`

This is good practice in general, enabling naming different sections of code via function names, executing the code only when run as `__main__`, by including a `__main__` stanza, and thus enabling importing `setup.py` and using specific functionality that may be relevant to outside code (e.g., an installation framework) without necessarily running all code--e.g., without running the function `setuptools.setup`.

The question presents a minimal working example, so a small `setup.py` is relevant in the question. I am writing this section as recommendation for what to do in actual packages, not in questions.

The same observation applies to module and function docstrings inside `setup.py`.

Also, I recommend the top-down arrangement of functions: callers above callees, because this layout is more readable.

I used `os.extsep` for generality, though using a dot I think will still work, and is more readable.

### Arrangement of package

As I noted earlier, the only change to the question's example that was needed to avoid the build error "relative cimport beyond main package is not allowed" was the addition of either an `__init__.py` or an `__init__.pxd`, and either an absolute `cimport` inside `driver.pyx` or the renaming of the `Extensions`.

### Removing the file `__init__.py`

In the final version, I removed the file `__init__.py` that is in the same directory with `setup.py`. My understanding is that this file has no effect in this example. If the example is intended to have `test/` as the main package's directory, then any `__init__.py` would appear inside `test/`.

If `test/` is actually an auxiliary package of tests for the main package, then the `__init__.py` would be part of the main package, and unrelated to the `test/` package. However, in that case, it seems that there would be a `setup.py` file above `myProject/`, which would be responsible for building both the main package, and the test-harness package.

### Using absolute imports

[The default `language_level` in `cython < 3.0.0` is 2](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/0.29.24/docs/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.rst#compiler-directives), even on Python 3:

> `language_level` *(2/3/3str)*
> Globally set the Python language level to be used for module
> compilation. Default is compatibility with Python 2.
> To enable Python 3 source code semantics, set this to 3 (or 3str)
> at the start of a module or pass the "-3" or "--3str"
> command line options to the compiler.

The question uses Python 3.5 and `cython == 0.23.4`, so this is the case.

The default Cython semantics are [changing in `cython >= 3.0.0`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/3.0.0a8/CHANGES.rst#other-changes-3):

> The default language level was changed to `3str`, i.e. Python 3 semantics, ...

With both Python 2 and Python 3 semantics (passing `compiler_directives=dict(language_level=3)`, or installing the pre-release `cython == 3.0.0a8`), the first two solutions (which use relative imports) do work.

Nonetheless, [absolute imports are recommended by PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages) if the import system is incorrectly configured ...

Absolute imports are also robust to refactoring a package's structure. They are explicit, and explicit is better than implicit ([PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

The resulting module `driver.pyx` after this change would be:

```
from example_package import other
from example_package cimport other
```

The `setup.py` code in this answer is based on what I have written in the file [`download.py`](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd/blob/main/download.py) of the [Python package `dd`](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd).