# Why doesn't my Cython cimport for a pxd file work?

Tags: python, cython, distutils, cimport

I'm new to Cython, so I might be missing something obvious, but I've read through the documentation and been banging my head against this for a while.

I have a `*.pyx` file that I build using a `setup.py` file as follows:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("path/to/helpers.pyx"),
)
```

That works fine, and I can now `import path.to.helpers` from sister directories and subdirectories without any issues.

Now, recently I decided I want to add a `helpers.pxd` file as well, so I can `cimport` parts of it to other Cython modules. I've added a `helpers.pxd` in `path/to` to facilitate this, but when I try to `cimport path.to.helpers`, I get

```
path/to/helpers.pxd not found
```

errors. Do I need to change something in my `setup.py` file to allow `cimport`ing from the `*.pxd` file?

None of the docs I've found say anything about doing this, and I feel like I've tried everything without any luck. Ideas?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115159/pxd-relative-cimport-works-for-language-level-2-but-not-for-3

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083432/how-to-import-depending-cython-modules-from-parent-folder-in-python

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555927/cython-relative-cimport-beyond-main-package-is-not-allowed

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed this after hours of banging my head against it. `*.pxd` files are much more finicky about `path` than `*.pyx` files, it turns out. I have no idea why. Anyway, just adding the path to my `*.pxd` file fixed the problem. My `setup.py` for `path/to/helpers.*` stays the same, but whenever I'm using any other `*.pyx` files that need access to `path.to.helpers`, I make sure the path to `path/to/helpers` is included as an `include-dir`, like:

`cython *.pyx *.pxd -a --cplus --include-dir ../some/path`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `__init__.py` to your `path/to/` directory. That works with distutils I believe.