# How to import depending cython modules from parent folder in python

Tags: python, c++, cython, cythonize

Imagine the following folder structure:

```
/project
  run.py
  /Helper
    Helper.pxd
    Helper.pyx
    setup.py
  /Settings
    Settings.pxd
    Settings.pyx
    setup.py
```

Helper uses the types Settings and PySettings defined in Settings.pxd. Therefor in Helper.pxd I'm doing:

```
from Settings cimport Settings, PySettings
```

In the setup.py in the Helper directory I put

```
include_path=[".", "../Settings/"]
```

in the cythonize command. Thus Helper knows about Settings and everything compiles.

In run.py I'd like to import Settings as well as Helper. The Settings import works fine but when doing

```
import Helper.Helper
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Helper.Helper
  File "../Settings/Settings.pxd", line 6, in init Helper
AttributeError: module 'Settings' has no attribute 'PySettings'
```

This issue disappears as soon as everything is in the same directory.

For the sake of completeness you'll find the whole code below:

/project/run.py

```
import Settings.Settings as S
import Helper.Helper as H

settings = S.PySettings()
settings.doSomething()

H.PyMyFunction(settings)
```

/project/Helper/Helper.pxd

```
from Settings cimport Settings, PySettings

cdef extern from "../../cppCode/Helper/Helper.h":
  void myFunction(Settings settings)
```

/project/Helper/Helper.pyx

```
#distutils: sources = [../../cppCode/Helper/Helper.cpp, ../../cppCode/Settings/Settings.cpp]
#distutils: language = c++

def PyMyFunction(PySettings settings):
  myFunction(settings.c_settings)
```

/project/Helper/setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools.extension import Extension

extensions = [
  Extension("Helper", ["Helper.pyx"])
]

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, include_path=[".", "../Settings/"]))
```

/project/Settings/Settings.pxd

```
cdef extern from "../../cppCode/Settings/Settings.h":
  cdef cppclass Settings:
    Settings() except +
    void doSomething()

cdef class PySettings:
  cdef Settings c_settings
```

/project/Settings/Settings.pyx

```
#distutils: sources = ../../cppCode/Settings/Settings.cpp
#distutils: language = c++

cdef class PySettings:
  def __cinit__(self):
    self.c_settings = Settings()

  def doSomething(self):
    self.c_settings.doSomething()
```

/project/Settings/setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools.extension import Extension

extensions = [
  Extension("Settings", ["Settings.pyx"])
]

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(extensions))
```

Comment: Did you see [What is __init_.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448271/5769463)

Comment: Yes, I also tried to put `__init__.py` files in all the directories. But it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115159/pxd-relative-cimport-works-for-language-level-2-but-not-for-3

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555927/cython-relative-cimport-beyond-main-package-is-not-allowed

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612483/why-doesnt-my-cython-cimport-for-a-pxd-file-work

Answer (score 6):

"`include_path`" is for C includes. It has no influence on where Python looks for pxd files.

You usually want one setup file, at the top level. A better way of doing it is probably:

```
setup.py
project/
  run.py
  __init__.pxd
  Settings/
    __init__.pxd
    Settings.pyx/pxd
  Helper/
    __init__.pxd
    Helper.pyx/pxd
```

This will create a single module called "package" which will all be built at once and installed at once. Once installed your user would be able to do `from project import whatever`.

You'll notice I've added some [`__init__.pxd` files](https://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html#init-pxd). These serve basically the same purpose as `__init__.py` files, except they identify folders as (sub)packages for Cython's cimport mechanism.

Helper .pxd then starts:

```
from project.Settings.Settings cimport Settings, PySettings
```

I've used a full rather than relative import because `cimport` and relative imports seems a bit unreliable.

Setup.py is as follows:

```
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = cythonize("project/*/*.pyx")

setup(ext_modules=ext_modules)
```

You are welcome to explicitly use `Extension` but for something simple it seemed easier to send the file pattern directly to cythonize.

---

I've only tested the Cythonize stage of this since I don't have the C++ files needed to compile and run it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly! I have a few follow up comments:

Comment: 1) run.py (where I use the cython modules in) has to be above the project folder where setup.py is. Otherwise I can not do `from cythonCode.Settings.Settings import PySettings`, right?
2) I don't get it to work when using extensions. I don't know what the problem is. If you don't mind having another look at it I created this git: https://github.com/zyzzler/cython-test.git (feel free to use `source setup_venv.sh` to have all the packages). I have a `setup_with_extensions.py`with my approach so far.
3) I don't understand the output of `run.py`. The constructor is called 3 times.

Comment: 1) I'd imagine that run.py is part of the package, so should be in the project directory (so if you use setup.py to install it should get installed with everything else) - obviously you may need to change the imports in run.py to match where it's located. 2) I think that the names of the extensions should be dotted (e.g. the first argument should be `"project.Settings.Settings"`). 3)  I'm not immediately able to test any of this, so I don't know at the moment.

Comment: 1) run.py is actually just the file I want to test the modules with. So right now (with run.py in the same location as setup.py) I can do `from cythonCode.Settings.Settings import PySettings` for instance. Putting run.py in the cythonCode folder I don't get the imports to work anymore. But probably I won't need it like this.
2) Thant's it! Works perfectly! Thanks again!