# Set setuptools to create cimportable package with headers availible

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, cimport

I try to implement the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57480599/7482208, but I am stuck on cimporting one package from another.

The code is here: https://github.com/iamishalkin/setuptools_cython_question

What I want is to have one independent package `wrap` from wrapper folder such that you can use it without `cust` package.

And I also want to be able to create custom functions by inheriting `FuncWrapper` class from `wrap`.

What I do:

- Firstly I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` in `wrapper` folder (this is what I am doing wrong, I suppose, as it gives me only binary file)
- Next `pip instal dist/(some_name).whl`
- Next I add `import wrap` and `include_dirs=wrap.get_include()` to `custom/setup.py` like it is done in `numpy`
- I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` in `custom` folder and this fails, on the first step no files except binary one were created

So the question is: how to add `.pxd` files to the final package.

I also tried `sdist` which does not compile cython code but just copies it.

Comment: Have you checked [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57483789/4720025) there?

Comment: I think the answer starts from ["If you want to expose the C-level interface of your library for other libraries to cimport from, use package_data to install the .pxd files"](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules) however I've never _really_ understood setup.py and it just seems to ignore package data

Comment: @ArdaAytekin It's a good approach to the specific problem (if you're allowed to change the C interface); the `BinaryOp` version would still need some way of installing .pxd files to be useful as a library (otherwise users can't easily inherit a `cdef class` from `BinaryOp` so it doesn't really avoid _this_ problem

Comment: @ArdaAytekin Yes, I saw it, but I am not able to change c code unfortunately

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33555927/1959808

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56115159/1959808

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in a comment, [the Cython documentation recommends putting .pxd files in `package_data` to install them](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules). This necessitates a slightly different structure:

```
| setup.py
+ wrapper
   | wrap.pxd
   | wrap.pyx
   | __init__.py # just so it's recognised as a package
                 # may be unnecessary with recent Python versions
```

setup.py then creates a "package" called wrapper (this is modified from your version so it's possible it could be simplied further):

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

NAME = "some_name"

ext_abc = Extension(name="wrapper.wrap",
                    sources=["wrapper/wrap.pyx"]
                    )

EXTENSIONS = [
    ext_abc
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        zip_safe=False,
        name=NAME,
        packages=["wrapper"],
        cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext},
        ext_modules=cythonize(EXTENSIONS, language_level=3),
        package_data = {
            "wrapper": ["*.pxd"],
    },
        )
```

Note that I've changed the name of the extension to "wrapper.wrap" to ensure that it's installed as part of the package. The `package_data` is then able to recognised .pxd files as part of `wrapper` that you want to install. *This doesn't work unless you put it in a "package"*.

You then install it. I just installed it with `python3 setup.py install` but I'm sure going through a wheel does largely the same thing.

---

For another module to use you file it's very simple:

```
from wrapper.wrap cimport FuncWrapper
```

The setup.py for that other module need have nothing special - you definitely don't need anything like `include_dirs=wrap.get_include()`.

If you want to have an interface where you don't need submodules so can just do

```
from wrapper cimport FuncWrapper
```

then just use an `__init__.py` containing:

```
from .wrap import *
```

and an `__init__.pxd` containing:

```
from wrapper.wrap cimport * # relative import is a little broken in Cython I think
```

---

I'm sure there are other ways of doing this - I've only really used setuptools for compiling Cython stuff and never really worried about distributing too much so am not an expert - but this looks to be the standard approach.

Comment: Thank you, I've also found example on github, but have not implemented this yet for my problem to answer https://github.com/jkleckner/cython_example

Comment: Something strange is happening, when I add `from wrap cimport *` to `__init__.pxd` building custom I get `__init__.pxd:1:0: 'wrap.pxd' not found`  and if I do not do this, then when I call `PyClass().py_wrap(add, 5, 5)` I get `Argument 'func' has incorrect type (expected wrap.FuncWrapper, got wrapper.wrap.FuncWrapper)`

Comment: I've edited the answer so `__init__.p*` works (I also had to remove the slightly odd attempt to import itself from wrap.pxd)

Comment: I have applied this changes but this does not solved the problem with types. I updated github repo with question. My collegue have solved this problem with poetry, and when I understand the solution I'll share it here

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, I was able to get this working using a MANIFEST.in file placed in the top-level directory. The contents are simply:

```
include MANIFEST.in
global-include *.pyx
global-include *.pxd
global-exclude *.pyc *.pyo *.pyd
```

I use this in addition to what the selected answer recommends.