# Packaging interdependent Cython extensions

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, python-packaging

I have written 3 Cython extensions, and I would like to package them in a tidy way that I can distribute to coworkers to use in Python, without them needing a C compiler installed.

Directory structure is:

```
myproject\
|---- setup.py
|---- gamma-source\
|      |---- eta.pxd
|      |---- eta.pyx
|      |---- omega.pxd
|      |---- omega.pyx
|      |---- rho.pxd
|      |---- rho.pyx
```

Where `omega` has a cimport from `rho`, `eta` has a cimport and an import from `omega`, `rho` has cimports from `eta` and `omega`.

My `setup.py` is:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

__version__ = '0.1.0'

exts = [Extension("eta",
                  sources = ["gamma-source\\eta.pyx"]),
        Extension("omega",
                  sources = ["gamma-source\\omega.pyx"]),
        Extension("rho",
                  sources = ["gamma-source\\rho.pyx"]),
       ]

setup(name="gamma",
      version=__version__,
      ext_modules = cythonize(exts,
                              compiler_directives = {'language_level':'3'}
                              ),
      zip_safe = False,
      )
```

and using `python setup.py install` gets me working on my own machine, but:

1. The `.pyd` files are dropped into my `site-packages` folder rather than being in `site-packages\rho`, which is untidy.
2. This method requires me to `import eta, omega, rho` instead of `from gamma import omega` or `import gamma.omega`, which I would prefer if possible.

I tried changing setup.py to:

```
exts = [Extension("gamma.eta",
                  sources = ["gamma-source\\eta.pyx"]),
        Extension("gamma.omega",
                  sources = ["gamma-source\\omega.pyx"]),
        Extension("gamma.rho",
                  sources = ["gamma-source\\rho.pyx"]),
       ]
```

but `python setup.py develop` gives me:

```
error: could not create 'gamma\rho.cp39-win_amd64.pyd': No such file or directory.
```

I then tried putting a `gamma` directory into `myproject`, and then it would install, but I found that
`from gamma import omega` worked but importing either `eta` and `rho` gave me

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rho'
```

I then tried changing the imports from `from omega cimport omega_class` to `from .omega cimport omega_class` in the hope that that would get the modules to find each other, but that wouldn't compile - `eta.pyx` couldn't find `omega_class`.

I tried adding a blank `__init__.py` file to `gamma-source`, but that also wouldn't compile.

Where am I going wrong? How should I package these extensions into a coherent unit? I'm happy to share more detailed error info from any of the approaches I took, but not sure which of them would be fruitful.

This question looked like it might be hitting the same issue, but it wasn't clear to me how I would apply the given solution:
[Building Python package containing multiple Cython extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560007/building-python-package-containing-multiple-cython-extensions)

Comment: Instead of gamma_source, try renaming the package gamma. Add an __init__.py so that cython knows it is a package, Also, do relative cimports (from .omega cimport omega_class). What is the error in this case?

Comment: https://github.com/jakevdp/cython_template worked for me in a somewhat similar case

Comment: @Golden Rockefeller Renamed the package `gamma`. Added a blank `__init__.py`. Using the relative cimports gave me "relative cimport beyond main package is not allowed." Changing the cimports to "from gamma.omega cimport omega_class" successfully built, but at run time I got "ImportError: cannot import name 'rho; from 'gamma' (<path to `__init__.py`>)"
Changing the extension names to `gamma.omega` etc successfully built, but at run time I got "ValueError: gamma.omega.omega_class size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 24 from PyObject".

Comment: @GoldenRockefeller Aha! Having the extension names as `gamma.omega` *and* the relative imports *and* the blank `__init__.py` worked! Thank you - I was banging my head on this for 2 days, going round and round in circles.