# Cython: cannot get relative cimport to work

Tags: python, cython, cimport

I am testing relative imports in Cython to use in my own project, but I can't seem to get it working. I also tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33572497/16264548), but still couldn't get it to work.

I am using Cython doc's [example](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types), but changing the file structure so that it resembles a package:

```
.
├── main.py
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── landscaping.pyx
    ├── shrubbing.pxd
    └── shrubbing.pyx
```

The shrubbing.pxd and .pyx files are the same as the docs, but I changed the landscaping.pyx file to use relative imports.

```py
# landscaping.pyx
from . cimport shrubbing
from . import shrubbing

def main():
    cdef shrubbing.Shrubbery sh
    sh = shrubbing.standard_shrubbery()
    print("Shrubbery size is", sh.width, 'x', sh.length)
```

However, when I run `python setup.py`:

```py
# setup.py
import sys
sys.argv = ["setup.py", "build_ext", "--inplace"]

from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = [
    Extension('landscaping', ['src/landscaping.pyx']),
    Extension('shrubbing', ['src/shrubbing.pyx']),
]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
    include_dirs=['.'],
)
```

It gives this error:

```
error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from . cimport shrubbing
^
------------------------------------------------------------

src/landscaping.pyx:1:0: relative cimport beyond main package is not allowed
```

I've been stuck on this for weeks, trying to change `setuptools.setup` arguments such as the `include_dirs` and whatnot, but without success.

**Edit 1**:
I know the problem is that when compiling, the main package becomes the folder the file being compiled lies in, but my `include_dirs` is the base directory above `src/`, so is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Whatever the motivation to split into two extensions, sources for `landscaping` don't include `shrubbing.pyx` - it is not supposed to work

Comment: That is not true. If I remove the relative imports and put the three files in the base directory, it works. Also the docs also generates two separate files.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a [bug](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3442), and should be fixed with [this](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/4552) pull request! Note that it is not working in the current version 29.3, but should be fixed in the next version.